# Convert indices to vectors in Numpy

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

Suppose that we have this data:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([1,0,1,2,1,2])
```

I want convert it to this:

```
[0 1 0
 1 0 0
 0 1 0
 0 0 1
 0 1 0
 0 0 1]
```

How can I do this in Numpy (or other related packages)? We have [`ind2vec`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/ind2vec.html) function in MATLAB for doing this.

Comment: What's the logic behind such conversion ?

Comment: This is for output of neural network when we have softmax function as transfer function of output layer for classification purpose.

Comment: How is the output related to input?

Comment: Is your input [101] or [1,0,1]

Comment: I added some information. This is same as `ind2vec` function in `MATLAB`. It is converting ndices to vectors.

Comment: why is the last pairing `0 1`?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham. Same as first input of `data` we should have `[0 1]`.

Comment: Please use a `data` vector with something other than `0`s and `1`s.  It will make the example much easier to understand.

Comment: You infer the length of 2nd dimension from largest value in data?

Comment: @swenzel. We select the column based on `data` value and insert 1 in that cell and set other values (in that specific row) equal to 0.

Comment: @user2991243 I understood that. But how do you know that there is not a column of 0s missing, just because the last index didn't occur in data?

Comment: @swenzel. Yes. That's true. It's based on largest value in data ;-)

Answer (score 4):

A fairly common way to do this in NumPy is to compare `data` with `arange` and cast the boolean array to integer type:

```
>>> (np.arange(3) == data[:,None]).astype(int)
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1]])
```

More generally, if you want to specify `N` columns (similar to Matlab's function) here's a function wrapping the necessary steps. You can pass the list of indices `ind` as a Python list or a NumPy array:

```
def ind2vec(ind, N=None):
    ind = np.asarray(ind)
    if N is None: 
        N = ind.max() + 1
    return (np.arange(N) == ind[:,None]).astype(int)
```

Then for example:

```
>>> ind2vec([4,0,2])
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])

>>> ind2vec([1,3,2,1,0], N=10)
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Really pretty answer :) (quick fix, wouldn't it be `ind.max()+1`?)

Comment: @user2991243 what are you going to do with the result? Maybe you don't even need to convert it to int.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([1,0,1,2,1,2])

idx = np.zeros((data.size, data.max()+1))
idx[np.arange(data.size), data] = 1
```

Comment: I would replace `range` for `np.arange`, same behaviour but faster for large `N`.

Comment: @imaluengo guess that depends on python version... np.arange will create an array where xrange in 2.x and range in 3.x won't.

Comment: I don't know to what extent is that true and numpy handles generators without converting them to lists beforehand. A quick `timeit` in the example question (with `N = 6`) already shows that `np.arange` is 4 times faster than `xrange` (in python 2.7, `4.5us` for indexing with `xrange` while `1.2us` for `np.arange`). But this is currently out of the scope of the current question.

Comment: @imaluengo Never tried, but apparently you're right... from the timings I assume `numpy` *is* turning the generator into an array. But ajcr's answer is better anyway :D

Answer (score 0):

```
def ind_to_vec(data):
    maxd = max(data)
    mind = min(data)
    b = np.zeros([len(data),maxd-mind+1])
    for ii in range(mind,maxd+1):
        for jj in range(len(data)):
            if data[jj]==ii:
                b[jj,ii]=1
    return b
```

This steps through every possible value in the input array, and checks to see what value it is. It then populates an otherwise zeroed array with a 1 in the column that is for that value. Output for your input data is

```
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.],
[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
[ 0.,  1.,  0.],
[ 0.,  0.,  1.],
[ 0.,  1.,  0.],
[ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
```